# Unusual long save times for all files except faces-config.xsp - no issues in small projects

Tags: eclipse, xpages, domino-designer-eclipse

Every time I am inside a `Java` or `XPages/Custom Control` file and save the file it takes an unusual amount of time to complete the save operation (about 5 seconds).
While saving, the cursor rapidly switches between the standard cursor and the loading wheel - looks like it does so by the millisecond.

When inside a small project I have no issues - but after working a while and the project gets bigger the issue starts to show and worsens the bigger the project gets. It almost seems like the Domino Designer is trying to save every file in the project (which it does not do).

The only file I don't have this issue with is the `faces-config.xml`.

As mentioned above, I'm working with the IBM Domino Designer (9.0.1FP6). Also, the Domino Designer is running inside a Windows 10 Virtual Machine using VirtualBox.

The problem started to appear a couple of weeks ago.
No problems before that.

"Build Automatically" is not enabled and I made no significant changes to preferences - at least not that I'm aware of.

Comment: Look at this https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21617708 and see if changing your JVM memory settings helps

Comment: Unfortunately this does not help.

Comment: Do you have the same problem when working on a local replica / local dev server?

Comment: @SvenHasselbach Nope - no problems on the local dev... thanks for that! :)
What could be the problem with the "non-local" server?

Comment: So you are working on a (remote) server? Yes, that will slow things down due to network latency. Recommendation: always work on a local replica

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten well, okay that makes sence but wouldn't that "always" affect the save time? I've always worked this way and now is the first time I have problems.

Comment: @VIC agree, maybe something changed in your network?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of .... anyway, since moving to `local` does resolve the problem, I will do so. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As *Sven Hasselbach* and *Per Henrik Lausten* pointed out the issue might be the server I am working on - Working on a `local replica` resolves the issue.

Comment: The best way for XPages development is using a local dev server on your machine. You have full control, you can crash & restart it without interferenting other devs and you can use remote debugging. IBM has released a community server for this puropse.